# MongooseJS findAndUpdate within Find loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Been banging my head in the wall on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  With MongooseJS, I'm doing a Model.find and then looping through those results and doing a findAndUpdate.

(basically, get list of URLS from MongooseJS, "ping" each URL to get a status, then update the DB with the status).

Schema

```
var serverSchema = new Schema({
  github_id: { type: String, required: true },
  url: { type: String, required: true },
  check_interval: Number,
  last_check: {
    response_code: Number,
    message: String,
    time: Date
  },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
})
```

Here's a code snippet:

```
// Doesn't work
Server.find(function (err, items) {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    var query = {url: item.url}
    Server.findOneAndUpdate(query, {updated_at: Date.now()}, function (err, doc) {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      console.log(doc)
    })
  })
})

// Works!
var query = {url: 'https://google.com'}
Server.findOneAndUpdate(query, {updated_at: Date.now()}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  console.log(doc)
})
```

With debugging on, I can see that the .find() is getting the data I want.  However, it seems that he findOneAndUpdate within the .find() never runs (item.url is set correctly) and I don't get any errors, it just doesn't run.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without `find` and then `update` you can do this in only one `update` operation

```
Server.update({}, { $set: { updated_at: Date.now() } }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return console.log(err) {
        console.log(doc)
    }
})
```

In case you need to loop on items for specific reason to handle urls then try the code below

```
var Server = require('../models/server');
Server.find(function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err)
        } else {
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                var query = { url: item.url }
                Server.update(query, { $set: { updated_at: Date.now() } }, function(err, doc) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err)
                    console.log(doc)
                })
            })
        }
    })
```

Mongodb Connection:

```
var secrets = require('./secrets');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
    var connect = function() {
        var mongoLink = "";
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            mongoLink = secrets.db.prod;
        } else {
            mongoLink = secrets.db.dev;
        }

        mongoose.connect(mongoLink, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error connecting to: ' + mongoLink + '. ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connected to: ' + mongoLink);
            }
        });
    };
    connect();

    mongoose.connection.on('error', console.log);
    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', connect);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I do need to loop through the list from find, I put in your code, and it still doesn't run the update (via debug I see the .find() run, but not the .update)

Comment: are you sure that item and ```item.url``` inside ```forEach``` are giving the expected values ... also what is the schema of ```Server``` can you please update the question with the schema  ?

Comment: Added the schema.  Yes, if I put a console.log(query) just before the Server.findOneAndUpdate it outputs correctly.

Comment: Also, the full code is here: https://github.com/chriskacerguis/servercheck/blob/master/worker.js

Comment: So you mean that ```Server.update``` is not running at all ? ... so the code is not reaching the callback function  ?

Comment: I just executed the exact same code on a test document that i have and it updated the documents correctly ... its really weird that the update operation is just not running at all !!

Comment: What version of mongo / Node are you using?

Comment: Would you mind updating your code with where/how are you connecting / disconnecting from the mongodb?

Comment: Sure i updated the code with mongodb connection, if you need the model code i can add it as well